# Spark-submit: undefined function parse_url

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

The function - ***parse_url*** always works fine if we working with spark-sql throw sql-client (via thrift server), IPython, pyspark-shell, but it doesn't work throw **spark-submit** mode:

```
/opt/spark/bin/spark-submit --driver-memory 4G --executor-memory 8G main.py
```

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/spark/***/main.py", line 167, in <module>
    )v on registrations.ga = v.ga and reg_path = oldtrack_page and registration_day = day_cl_log  and date_cl_log <= registration_date""")
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/context.py", line 552, in sql
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 538, in __call__
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 40, in deco
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: undefined function parse_url;
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

So, we are using workaround here:

```
def python_parse_url(url, que, key):
    import urlparse
    ians = None
    if que == "QUERY":
        ians = urlparse.parse_qs(urlparse.urlparse(url).query)[key][0]
    elif que == "HOST":
        ians = urlparse.urlparse(url).hostname
    elif que == "PATH":
        ians = urlparse.urlparse(url).path
    return ians

def dc_python_parse_url(url, que, key):
    ians = None
    try:
        ians = python_parse_url(url, que, key)
    except:
        pass
    return ians

sqlCtx.registerFunction('my_parse_url', dc_python_parse_url)
```

Please, any help with this issue?

Comment: Read documentation to see functions available by Spark: https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html or by Hive: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Spark >= 2.0**

Same as below, but use `SparkSession` with Hive support enabled:

```
SparkSession.builder.enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
```

**Spark < 2.0**

`parse_url` is not a *classic sql function*. It is a Hive UDF and as such requires `HiveContext` to work:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext, SQLContext

sc = SparkContext()

sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
hivContext = HiveContext(sc)

query = """SELECT parse_url('http://example.com/foo/bar?foo=bar', 'HOST')"""

sqlContext.sql(query)
## Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
##   ...
## AnalysisException: 'undefined function parse_url;'

hivContext.sql(query)
## DataFrame[_c0: string]
```

Comment: Also stands for `collect_list` and `collect_set`; they require `HiveContext`.

Comment: @Szilard Spark has native `collect_list` and `collect_set` since 2.0.

Comment: @ zero323: That is true, I should have been more specific. My comment on `collect_list` refers to Spark <2.0 which (I need to use for legacy purposes).